# Design principles behind std::ratio<>

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, rational-numbers

I was looking at the class [`std::ratio<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio) from the C++11 standard that allows to make compile-time rational arithmetic.

I found the template design and the operations implemented with classes overly complex and did not find any reason why they could not just use a more straightforward and intuitive approach by implementing a really simple rational class and defining `constexpr` functions for the operators. The result would have been a class easier to use and the compile-time advantages would have remained.

Does anyone have any idea of the advantages of the current `std::ratio<>` design compared to a simple class implementation using `constexpr`? Actually, I can't manage to find any advantage to the current implementation.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html

Comment: Isn't it compile-time (thus templates) vs runtime?

Comment: @Drakosha: `constexpr` is not a hint; in certain contexts (where a constant expression is required), a compiler *must* execute them at compile-time.

Comment: Try doing the same thing with `constexpr`. There are a lot of constraints on what you can label `constexpr`.

Comment: I actually already did the same with `constexpr`, [have a look](https://github.com/Morwenn/static_math/blob/master/include/static_math/rational.h). You can also find the tests (all done at compile-time) [here](https://github.com/Morwenn/static_math/blob/master/test/rational.cpp).

Comment: @Morwenn that's not enough. Now try using that `rational` thing as a template parameter.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Good point again.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When [N2661](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) was proposed, none of the proposal authors had access to a compiler which implemented `constexpr`.  And none of us were willing to propose something we could not build and test.  So whether or not a better design could have been done with `constexpr` was not even part of the consideration for the design.  The design was based on only those tools available to the authors at the time.

Comment: Of course you would come along with such a practical answer. :-]

Comment: @jon34yp: interesting that it turns out the questioner has asked two questions: (1) what were the design principles behind `std::ratio`, on which subject I think Howard is an authority. (2) what are the advantages of the current design, which could have all sorts of answers of which Howard is unaware, never having considered it :-)

Answer (score 16):

The constexpr solution solves completely different problem. `std::ratio` was created to be used as a bridge between variables that use different units, not as a mathematical tool. In these circumstances, you absolutely necessarily want the ratio to be part of the type. The constexpr solution won't work there. For example, it won't be possible to implement `std::duration` without a run-time space and runtime costs, because each duration object would need to carry its nominator/denominator information within the object.

Comment: Ditto for a reasonable <units> library where you would want fractional powers of the various dimensions but you a) wouldn't want to carry around three or five actual fractions and b) you would want dist + time to be a compiler type error not a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

> defining constexpr functions for the operator

You can still do this on top of the existing `std::ratio`:

```
#include <ratio>

// Variable template so that we have a value
template< 
    std::intmax_t Num, 
    std::intmax_t Denom = 1 
>
auto ratio_ = std::ratio<Num, Denom>{};

// Repeat for all the operators
template< 
    std::intmax_t A, 
    std::intmax_t B,
    std::intmax_t C,
    std::intmax_t D
>
constexpr typename std::ratio_add<std::ratio<A, B>, std::ratio<C, D>>::type
operator+(std::ratio<A, B>, std::ratio<C, D>) {}

// Printing operator
template< 
    std::intmax_t A, 
    std::intmax_t B
>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::ratio<A, B> r) {
    return os << decltype(r)::num << "/" << decltype(r)::den;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << ratio_<1,2> + ratio_<1,3> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
5/6
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::ratio` and its surrounding mechanisms will always run at compile-time, by virtue of template metaprogramming and type manipulation. `constexpr` is only required to run at runtime when a constant expression is required by C++ facilities (such a template parameters or initializing a `constexpr` variable).

So which is more important to you: compile-time execution, or being "more straightforward and intuitive"?

Comment: With `constexpr`, we can have both intuitive use AND compile-time execution for constant expressions, so with the exact same expressions than the templates. So both advantages at once seems pretty much of a fair trade.

Comment: @Morwenn: The point Nicol is trying to make is that if you use a `constexpr` in a situation where it is not required (say a regular expression inside a function) the `constexpr` can or cannot be evaluated at compile time, i.e. it might trigger a function call at runtime. Also note that functions that are `constexpr` can only use a subset of the language, so they might not yield such a natural design anyway.

Comment: @David: you can force a `constexpr` function in some other context to be evaluated at compile time, using tricks like `template <int N> struct compile_time_dammit { enum { value = N }; }; ... compile_time_dammit<some_constexpr_function()>::value;`. All of which is moot since the answer to the question has nothing to do with the pros and cons of `constexpr` :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop An optimizing compiler will probably compute the values of constexpr variables at compile-time anyway.

Comment: @jons34yp: It might. It might not. That's the point; the C++ spec *requires* template metaprogramming to happen at compile time.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just found this old answer. Didn't you mean "only required to run at compile time" instead of "at runtime"?